# why the size is different after exported sql file to local computer

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I exported one database, in phpmyadmin, this database info: size: 2.7 GiB, overhead:43.5 KiB, after I exported to my local computer(win 7), the size is :495 MB

Questions:

1.size: 2.7 GiB = 2.9 GB, why after exported to local computer, it is only  495 MB?

2.what does this mean 'overhead'?

Comment: Was it exported gzipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are deletes or updates some dbs don't free the memory slots by itself and the difference to the really needed space can be huge, especially after many updates and deletes.
For example an update can lead to a new used slot and a slot marked as empty  They just keep it for future needs. Some have a special command for compacting. But after exporting and importing all the unused space is freed.

Just try optimize table on the tables of your old db and compare them after.